# Elasticsearch can not retrive data with term & exist query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get data with Query:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
       "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                 "_id": 680541523427431170
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                 "field": "my_type"
               }
            }
          ]
       }
   }
}
```

However, this is no hit of this query, the document is:

```
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "680541523427431170",
  "_version" : 9,
  "_seq_no" : 275766,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "Id" : 680541523427431170,
    "artist_name" : [
      "MM"
    ],
    "my_type" : 2
  }
}
```

However, I can get another document with same query. = =

Here is my index mapping:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
                "artist_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "my_type": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "user_ids": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to reindex all the documents, or can I reindex only this one, regenerating inverted index for it.

Comment: it works for me. Can you share the index mapping?

Comment: @Val Sorry, I forgot it, I just add my index mapping above, thanks